# Image not showing despite being hardcoded - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

```
Rails 4.1
Ruby 2.1.1
```

I have the following in my view:

```
<% img_loc = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/cw/agent/avatar/#{agent.id.to_s}/thumb_#{a.img_name}"%>
<td><%= image_tag "#{img_loc}" %></td>
```

When I run this on my production server, the image does not show. My production log shows the following:

```
INFO -- : Started GET "/home/dnc/app/assets/images/cw/agent/avatar/11/thumb_myimage.jpg"
FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/home/dnc/app/assets/images/cw/agent/avatar/11/thumb_myimage.jpg"):
```

But when I check, the file /home/dnc/app/assets/images/cw/agent/avatar/11/thumb_myimage.jpg does exist. Any ideas?

Comment: try image_tag "/cw/agent/avatar/#{agent.id.to_s}/thumb_#{a.img_name}"

Comment: Just a note. No need to call `to_s` on `#{agent.id.to_s}`.

Comment: Damien: thanks for the tip. Rahul: this won't work, the / will give the same results. I had actually tried image_tag "cw/agent/avatar/#{agent.id.to_s}/thumb_#{a.img_name}" and it did not work. It turns out I had not cleared my browser's cache. When I did, it worked fine.

Comment: Try: `<%= image_tag "/cw/agent/avatar/11/thumb_myimage.jpg" %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Path Helpers**

One has to question why you're not using the [`asset path helpers`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) to give you access to the `images` directory:

```
<% img_loc = image_path("cw/agent/avatar/11/thumb_myimage.jpg") %>
```

--

[**Image Tag**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag)

Alternatively, and probably more appropriately, you should look at using `image_tag` with a relative path, as this will load the image you need without having to hard-code it:

```
<%= image_tag "cw/agent/avatar/11/thumb_myimage.jpg" %>
```

[image]

---

I understand your reasoning (you want to access images directly), but I don't get your method. Rails has a very robust relative path system, which should give you the flexibility to access the images as you need

Comment: I am using <%= image_tag "cw/agent/avatar/11/thumb_myimage.jpg" %>, I did not refresh and thought it did not work. See my note above in response to Rahul's comment. Thank you for the tip on the asset path helpers